# How to create a 'button' which is linked to a Media Document with custom Link text?

Tags: 8, media, files

I am trying to create the ability for a content editor to add a button to an entity which links to a Media Document. Essentially the requirements are that we can upload a file and that file is reusable so we don't have to upload every time and the text on the button is customisable.

Currently when I add a media reference field it just outputs the file as a download link using the Filename as the link text. I was hoping to be able to use something like Linkit but this just works in the WYSIWYG at the moment and also Linkit doesn't allow you to add the file within the same node form.

An interface like the link module would be fantastic. Where we could select the file in the URL field and then set the link text below.

[image: Link Module]

Is there anything which currently exists to do this? or maybe could someone point me in the right direction to code something that works this way? Possibly I could add an accompanying field to the below widget where you can leverage the media library whilst allowing for custom 'link text'.

[image]

Comment: Adding a field to this widget would be the media reference field. The idea behind media is that you add the field to the media type. For re-using media enable the media library. It has its own form mode, so enable the new field there as well.

Comment: Are you trying to link to the media entity, e.g. /media/123, or to the file referenced in the media item, e.g. /sites/default/files/media-123-document.pdf?

Comment: @sonfd I would like to link to the file itself.

Comment: @4k4 Yeah I realised I could add the field to the media type but I was hoping to reuse the file but be able to have different text on the button each time I use it. If the field is on the media type then I assume everywhere I use that file it would be the same value?

Comment: OK, then you need a compound field type like the mentioned Link module. Easier to implement, though, would be a paragraph type, but the compound field is more efficient, because it stores all values in the same node table.